# How to give custom action to a UITableCellView disclosure indicator OR how to make a DisclosureDetail button look like an indicator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom UITableCellView (subclass). I want it to have disclosure chevron on the right side. But I want to hook a custom action to clicking on that indicator, not a storyboard segue.

I can think of two possible paths, but I don't know how to complete either:

1) Set the cell accessory as `Detail` in the storyboard. In that case, I can use `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`. But I would need to figure out how to change the presentation so it wasn't the "circle i" thing, but rather the indicator chevron.

2) Set the cell accessory as `Disclosure Indicator` in the storyboard. When I do that, I get the presentation I want, but the `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` doesn't fire. So I need to find some other mechanism to hook an action to it being tapped.

*(Aside: Let's avoid the "You shouldn't do that" answers. Let's assume I know what I'm doing, even if I don't. My question wasn't "Should I do this?")*

Comment: How about adding your own button to your cell prototype that looks like a chevron, and assigning an action to it?

Comment: That almost makes too much sense @BlackRider. Is there a way to fetch the system chevron image to put on the button? It's not an option from the storyboard editor (varieties of the circle i are ironically).

Comment: I don't know of a way to extract the system chevron image asset, but it's easy enough to make a screenshot containing such a chevron, crop it and create a button image(s) from it :)

Comment: And of course, you can check out some icon libraries on the internets.